# XSLT How to get previous attribute value if my condition satisfied?

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT How to get previous attribute value if my condition satisfied?

I have tried to get the desired out but not succeeded can someone please assist me how to achieve this?

Here is my Zip.xml

```
<Zip>
        <ZipNotify Zip="1144" ZipNo="1" ZipTime="2010-09-02T11:15:30+10:00"/>
        <ZipDetail Zone="U" DepartZip="West" ArriveZip="West"/>
        <ZipCategoryDetail ZORE="false" />
        <ZipOrigin ZipOrigin="ABC002" Die="20:59:00"/>
        <ZipDestination ZipDestination="UVW001" Live="21:38:00"/>
        <ZipPath>
            <ZipSubject ZipSubjectType="Payed" ZipNum="1">
                <ZipRoute ZipLoc="ABC002" ZipStop="true" ZipDieTime="20:59:00" ZipDieTime1="20:59:00"/>
            </ZipSubject>
            <ZipSubject ZipSubjectType="Payed" ZipNum="2">
                <ZipRoute ZipLoc="BCD002" ZipStop="true" ZipLiveTime="21:00:40" ZipDieTime1="21:01:00"/>
                <ZipSpec Charge="false"/>
            </ZipSubject>
            <ZipSubject ZipSubjectType="Payed" ZipNum="3">
                <ZipRoute ZipLoc="CDE001" ZipStop="true" ZipLiveTime="21:03:40" ZipDieTime1="21:04:00"/>
                <ZipSpec Charge="true"/>
            </ZipSubject>
            <ZipSubject ZipSubjectType="Payed" ZipNum="4">
                <ZipRoute ZipLoc="DEF001" ZipStop="true" ZipLiveTime="21:05:40" ZipDieTime1="21:06:00"/>
                <ZipSpec Charge="true"/>
            </ZipSubject>
            <ZipSubject ZipSubjectType="Payed" ZipNum="5">
                <ZipRoute ZipLoc="EFG001" ZipStop="true" ZipLiveTime="21:07:40" ZipDieTime1="21:08:00"/>
                <ZipSpec Charge="true"/>
            </ZipSubject>
            <ZipSubject ZipSubjectType="Payed" ZipNum="5">
                <ZipRoute ZipLoc="UVW001" ZipStop="true" ZipLiveTime="21:38:00" ZipLiveTime1="21:38:00"/>
                <ZipSpec Charge="true"/>
            </ZipSubject>
        </ZipPath>
</Zip>
```

Here is my XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head/>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Zip/ZipPath/ZipSubject">
                <xsl:if test="/Zip/ZipPath/ZipSubject/ZipSpec/@Charge = 'true'">
                    <div>ZipLoc: <xsl:value-of select="/Zip/ZipPath/ZipSubject/ZipRoute/@ZipLoc"/> </div>
                    <div>Charge: <xsl:value-of select="/Zip/ZipPath/ZipSubject/ZipSpec/@Charge"/></div>
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Out Put I want is
I want to get the ZipLoc of previous ZipSubject where Charge="true"
Eg. For ZipNum="3" value Charge="true" so my out put must display previous ZipLoc="BCD002" (even though Charge="false" ZipNum="2") that’s it, it should not do further validation for ZipOrigin and for ZipDestination again it should check from the last ZipNum="5" if Charge="true" then simply it should use the same ZipLoc="UVW001"

Desired Output should be

```
BCD002UVW001
```

But my output is below. I have tried possible ways(I know its lack of experience with XSLT which is not an excuse) please help me to get the Desired Output

```
ZipLoc: ABC002
Charge: false
ZipLoc: ABC002
Charge: false
ZipLoc: ABC002
Charge: false
ZipLoc: ABC002
Charge: false
ZipLoc: ABC002
Charge: false
ZipLoc: ABC002
Charge: false
```

Comment: Not clear what finally is the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to get the ZipLoc of previous ZipSubject where Charge="true"*

Inside the context of `xsl:for-each`you can use the following XPath:

```
 "preceding-sibling::ZipSubject[1]/ZipRoute/@ZipLoc"
```

E.g, the following XSLT fragment show how to print ZipLog and Charge of preceding node only for those with Charge='true':

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Zip/ZipPath/ZipSubject[ZipSpec/@Charge = 'true']">
  <div>ZipLoc: <xsl:value-of 
       select="preceding-sibling::ZipSubject[1]/ZipRoute/@ZipLoc"/> 
  </div>
  <div>Charge: <xsl:value-of 
       select="preceding-sibling::ZipSubject[1]/ZipSpec/@Charge"/></div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be doing more work than you need.  The xPath below should get you the ZipLoc for the first case you mentioned.

```
/Zip/ZipPath/ZipSubject[@ZipNum = '3' AND ZipSpec/@Charge = 'true']/ZipRoute/@ZipLoc
```